# Revert a pull request - Shared Branches amongst developers

Tags: git, git-revert

I'm unfamiliar with git reverts,I've been asked to undo or remove an old pull request to a main branch since it will not be deployed. I added a diagram to illustrate, I hope someone can help revert pull request A effectively.

Currently, I tried to remove the actual codes 1 by 1 but its taking me sometime and might break the whole application if done this way.

[image]

Comment: So, you need to remove A but leave B, which happened later and was merged with A?  If any of the file overlapped, there's no automated way to do that.

Comment: So this is all pull requests that have been merged? A and B have been merged separately and now both exist on the main branch? `git revert a` in a new branch and pull request. Merge that to main, developers will get the revert when they merge or rebase main

Comment: If you used a merge commit, try reverting that specific commit, committing that new reversion, and pushing it to your main branch (or to another branch for PR, which is probably a good idea). Otherwise you can try reverting the individual commits from the original branch, depending how complicated the history is.

Comment: Thanks guys on the answers! Will try them out!